# Targeting a svg in React (styled components) to edit it

Tags: reactjs, svg

Hello I am trying to edit a SVG using styled components and I don't think I am targeting it correctly

Index.js code  `<img src={waves} alt="divider" />`

Elements.js code

```js
export const waves = styled.img`
   margin-top: 60px;
`;
```

Comment: if you define styped component 'waves', you should use it in React as <waves .../>; src attribute should contain a valid URL, not a reference to styled component